# Load SVG file in Xamarin with SkiaSharp

Tags: android, svg, xamarin, xamarin.android, skiasharp

From release 1.55.0 SkiaSharp has the support for reading SVG files.
The package has been release few days ago (10 Nov. 2016) and I couldn't find enough documentation on how to use it.

The following packages are required:
SkiaSharp 1.55.0
SkiaSharp Views & Layers 1.55.0
SkiaSharp.Svg 1.55.0-beta1

The first question is what's the best way to load an SKSvg in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here two possible solutions to start working with SkiaSharp that are working for me:

**Loading SVG from Asset folder (or subfolder):**

```
public SKSvg LoadAnSvgFromAssets(Context ctx, string assetSvgFileLoc)
    {
        var assets = ctx.Assets;
        var svg = new SKSvg();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(assets.Open(assetSvgFileLoc)))
            {
              svg.Load(stream.BaseStream);
              return svg;
            }
    }
```

where "assetSvgFileLoc" is the svgFilename.svg to load, including (if it's the case) the path inside Asset folder (e.g. "subf1/subf2/mysvg.svg").

**Loading SVG as RAW Resource**

```
public SKSvg LoadAnSvgFromResources(Context ctx, string svgName))
  {
    var resId = ctx.Resources.GetIdentifier(svgName, "raw", ctx.PackageName);           
    var svg = new SKSvg();
    using (var stream = ctx.Resources.OpenRawResource(resId))
    {
        svg.Load(stream);
        return svg;
    }
}
```

In this case the file is inside the Resources subfolder "raw" and the "svgName" is the filename of our svg without extension.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the accepted answer, here is how to load the `SKSvg` from a URL.

```
SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     svg.Load(new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(new Uri(ResourceUrl))));
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code, it works great. I can have the SVG in PCL, iOS or Android folder.

Just remember to include the Assembly in path.

```
var assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (var s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssembly.Core.Hold.svg"))
{
    if (s != null)
    {
        svg = new SKSvg();
        svg.Load(s);
        using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
        {
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, paint);
        }
    }
}
```