# How to load file .svg with SkiaSharp on Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

How to load file `.svg` with [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) on Xamarin Forms (Android and iOS).

I tried [Load SVG file in Xamarin with SkiaSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692945/load-svg-file-in-xamarin-with-skiasharp), but i can't load it.

I tried to use [SkiaSharp.Extended](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended) and refer to their Demos, but still cannot load it.

Am I doing anything wrong?

please help me!

Comment: Please send your code!

Comment: Just popping in here to say that SkiaSharp.Svg is a bit old and has not received any actual love in a long time. I would suggest looking at https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Svg.Skia by Wiesław Šoltés. He has worked actual magic and has a library that has become more powerful than you can possibly imagine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**B1**> Create a folder `Images` in your project `Xamarin forms` and save image `.svg` at this. Make sure you select `Build Action` as "EmbeddedResource"

[image: EmbeddedResource]

**B2**> Download the required libraries like:
`SkiaSharp`, `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms`, `SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg`

**B3**> At `behind code`, use method `LoadSvg(xCanvasView.AutomationId)` at contructor of Page (`Example`: Page is `ListNewConversationPage`). And declare the required functions:

```
 private SKSvg svg;

        // Get file .svg to folder Images
    private static Stream GetImageStream(string svgName)
    {
        var type = typeof(ListNewConversationPage).GetTypeInfo();
        var assembly = type.Assembly;

        var abc = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Images.{svgName}");
        return abc;
    }


        private void LoadSvg(string svgName)
    {
        // create a new SVG object
        svg = new SKSvg();

        // load the SVG document from a stream
        using (var stream = GetImageStream(svgName))
            svg.Load(stream);
    }


        private void OnPageAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        svg = null;

        var page = (ContentPage)sender;
        LoadSvg(page.AutomationId);

        var canvas = (SKCanvasView)page.Content;
        canvas.InvalidateSurface();
    }

        private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var surface = e.Surface;
            var canvas = surface.Canvas;

            var width = e.Info.Width;
            var height = e.Info.Height;

            // clear the surface
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

            // the page is not visible yet
            if (svg == null)
                return;

            // calculate the scaling need to fit to screen
            float scaleX = width / svg.Picture.CullRect.Width;
            float scaleY = height / svg.Picture.CullRect.Height;
            var matrix = SKMatrix.MakeScale(scaleX, scaleY);

            // draw the svg
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, ref matrix);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

**B4**> At `.xaml` file, use it with `.svg` image is `image_part_circle.svg`

```
                   <forms:SKCanvasView x:Name="xCanvasView"
                                   PaintSurface="OnPainting"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                   AutomationId="image_part_circle.svg" />
```

Please see more at [SkiaSharp.Extended](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/tree/master/SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg)

Comment: Tks, It's work! I forget to select `Build Action` as "EmbeddedResource" after add .svg file

Answer (score 3):

The following packages need to be installed `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms`, `SkiaSharp.Extended`, and `SkiaSharp.Svg`. From there I created a custom Xamarin.Forms control like so:

```
    public class SvgImage : SKCanvasView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(string), typeof(SvgImage), default(string), propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

        public string Source
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(SourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty AssemblyNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AssemblyName), typeof(string), typeof(SvgImage), default(string), propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

        public string AssemblyName
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(AssemblyNameProperty);
            set => SetValue(AssemblyNameProperty, value);
        }

        static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var skCanvasView = bindable as SKCanvasView;
            skCanvasView?.InvalidateSurface();
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();

            InvalidateSurface();
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

            InvalidateSurface();
        }

        protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaintSurface(e);

            try
            {
                var surface = e.Surface;
                var canvas = surface.Canvas;

                canvas.Clear();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssemblyName))
                    return;

                var currentAssembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName);
                using (var stream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(AssemblyName + "." + Source))
                {
                    var skSvg = new SKSvg();
                    skSvg.Load(stream);

                    var skImageInfo = e.Info;
                    canvas.Translate(skImageInfo.Width / 2f, skImageInfo.Height / 2f);

                    var skRect = skSvg.ViewBox;
                    float xRatio = skImageInfo.Width / skRect.Width;
                    float yRatio = skImageInfo.Height / skRect.Height;

                    float ratio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);

                    canvas.Scale(ratio);
                    canvas.Translate(-skRect.MidX, -skRect.MidY);

                    canvas.DrawPicture(skSvg.Picture);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OnPaintSurface Exception: " + exc);
            }
        }
    }
```

I did have to specify the assembly and the folder path to the Svg image for it to find the image and any Svg images should be set to `EmbeddedResource`. Then to use the control in Xaml:

```
<controls:SvgImage AssemblyName="SkiaSharpSvgImage" Source="Resources.tux1.svg" />
```

The entire opensource test project I created can be viewed on [Github](https://github.com/nickpeppers/SkiaSharpSvgImage). Also, that repo could probably be improved but that was my first runabout using SkiaSharp Svg images and testing everything out.

Comment: It can be updated by loading svg by url. Just need to get stream from url, not from assembly.

Comment: I was only using .svg files from a local .Net Standard 2 library so I don't think I ever actually tested it using a url