# Does format of Images in Xamarin.Forms matter? How to improve performance?

Tags: image, xamarin, svg, png

I've been using .pngs across my app and i started to wonder - should i choose some other image formatting? Or it doesn't matter?

And if not, what are the other ways to improve performace image-wise? Usiung embedded images?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve the performance, you could add them as bundled content in your project instead of embedded images.

- Content/Local images - displaying images shipped with the application, including resolving native resolutions like iOS Retina or Android high-DPI versions of an image.
- Embedded images - images embedded as an assembly resource.

There are several tips about improving performance in the blog below for your reference.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/faster-startup-times-with-startup-tracing-on-android/

Comment: It's probably also worth looking at [using SkiaSharp to load an SVG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259473/how-to-load-file-svg-with-skiasharp-on-xamarin-forms) especially if you're worried about image sizes themselves. The SVG can be added to your shared project and loaded from there to size dynamically without becoming blurry.

Comment: @NickPeppers I was using those packages but some svg files show me in dark

Comment: I'd check those specific svg images. I never noticed any issues in any production apps when using SkiaSharp for SVG image but it's also been a while. It's probably worth checking out this other [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259473/how-to-load-file-svg-with-skiasharp-on-xamarin-forms/58262055#58262055)